# calculate the count by day

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that has columns `created_at` and `entities` that look like this

```
    created_at                         entities
2017-10-29 23:06:28     {'hashtags': [{'text': 'OPEC', 'indices': [0, ...
2017-10-29 22:28:20     {'hashtags': [{'text': 'Iraq', 'indices': [21,...
2017-10-29 20:01:37     {'hashtags': [{'text': 'oil', 'indices': [58, ...
2017-10-29 20:00:14     {'hashtags': [{'text': 'oil', 'indices': [38, ...
2017-10-27 08:44:30     {'hashtags': [{'text': 'Iran', 'indices': [19,...
2017-10-27 08:44:10     {'hashtags': [{'text': 'Oil', 'indices': [17, ...
2017-10-27 08:43:13     {'hashtags': [{'text': 'Oil', 'indices': [0, 4...
2017-10-27 08:43:00     {'hashtags': [{'text': 'Iran', 'indices': [19,.
```

I want to calculate the count of entities for each day. Basically I want to receive something like

```
created_at    number_of_entities
2017-10-29           4
2017-10-27           4
```

How to do that? I have `pandas 0.23.4`

Comment: Can you give a dataframe that has some more rows such that the output has different groupings? That would be a more useful example, thanks.

Comment: @timgeb added example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given

```
>>> df
           created_at  entities
0 2017-10-29 23:06:28         1
1 2017-10-29 22:28:20         2
2 2017-10-29 20:01:37         3
3 2017-10-29 20:00:14         4
4 2017-10-27 08:44:30         5
5 2017-10-27 08:44:10         6
6 2017-10-27 08:43:13         7
7 2017-10-27 08:43:00         8
```

with

```
>>> df.dtypes
created_at    datetime64[ns]
entities               int64
dtype: object
```

you can issue:

```
>>> pd.PeriodIndex(df['created_at'], freq='D').value_counts()
2017-10-29    4
2017-10-27    4
Freq: D, Name: created_at, dtype: int64
```

A nicer approach without the `PeriodIndex` constructor has been suggested by jezrael in the comments:

```
>>> df['created_at'].dt.to_period('D').value_counts()
2017-10-27    4
2017-10-29    4
```

With some additional renaming to match your output it starts to look suspiciously like jezrael's solution. ;)

```
>>> datecol = 'created_at'
>>> df[datecol].dt.to_period('D').value_counts().rename_axis(datecol).reset_index(name='number_of_entities')
  created_at  number_of_entities
0 2017-10-27                   4
1 2017-10-29                   4
```

Alternatively, you can set the index to the dates and then `resample`:

```
>>> df.set_index('created_at').resample('D').size()
created_at
2017-10-27    4
2017-10-28    0
2017-10-29    4
Freq: D, dtype: int64
```

... and if converting to your exact output is necessary:

```
>>> resampled = df.set_index('created_at').resample('D').size()
>>> resampled[resampled != 0].reset_index().rename(columns={0: 'number_of_entities'})
  created_at  number_of_entities
0 2017-10-27                   4
1 2017-10-29                   4
```

---

Some more context: `resample` is especially useful for arbitrary time intervals, for example "five minutes". The following example is taken directly from Wes McKinney's book "Python for Data Analysis".

```
>>> N = 15
>>> times = pd.date_range('2017-05-20 00:00', freq='1min', periods=N)
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'time': times, 'value': np.arange(N)})
>>> 
>>> df
                  time  value
0  2017-05-20 00:00:00      0
1  2017-05-20 00:01:00      1
2  2017-05-20 00:02:00      2
3  2017-05-20 00:03:00      3
4  2017-05-20 00:04:00      4
5  2017-05-20 00:05:00      5
6  2017-05-20 00:06:00      6
7  2017-05-20 00:07:00      7
8  2017-05-20 00:08:00      8
9  2017-05-20 00:09:00      9
10 2017-05-20 00:10:00     10
11 2017-05-20 00:11:00     11
12 2017-05-20 00:12:00     12
13 2017-05-20 00:13:00     13
14 2017-05-20 00:14:00     14
>>> 
>>> df.set_index('time').resample('5min').size()
time
2017-05-20 00:00:00    5
2017-05-20 00:05:00    5
2017-05-20 00:10:00    5
Freq: 5T, dtype: int64
```

Comment: What is the difference between `periodIndex` and using `groupby`?

Comment: @lapots you can achieve the same output with `groupby` as other answers have shown. Making use of a `PeriodIndex` or resampling is just employing the `pandas` tools specifically designed for handling periods. In your case, we're dealing with periods of days.

Comment: @lapots - there is difference `value_counts` by default sorting by counts, `groupby + size/count` not

Comment: Well, you can pass `sort=False` to `value_counts` whenever you want to.

Comment: @timgeb how to set second column name for periodIndex? when I convert it to dataframe it sets only single column `created_at`

Comment: @lapots - PeriodIndex here is not necessary, better are functions `.floor` if want datetimeindex or `.date` if want `date`s

Comment: @lapots I'm not exactly sure how the df you created looks like, but you can always set the `columns` attribute to whatever you like. If you want the names as shown in your question, I'd go with the resampling approach.

Comment: @jezrael It's just the first solution I came up with that works nicely if the column labels are not crucial (which might be useful for other readers). The second part of the answer deals with constructing a dataframe output then.

Comment: @timgeb - Standard solutions are another answers ;)

Comment: @timgeb - periods are nice for month periods, but for dates not, because is easier use `floor` or `date`s, what is not possible use for months.

Comment: @jezrael Hey, I'm not yet a master like you, so don't be surprised by unconventional approaches :D `dt.to_period` is cool, I've edited this in.

Comment: @timgeb - ya, I was thinking if get advice and then decide  - yes, why not? so `to_period` :)

Answer (score 2):

Using `groupby.size`

```
# Convert to datetime dtype if you haven't.
df1.created_at = pd.to_datetime(df1.created_at)

df2 = df1.groupby(df1.created_at.dt.date).size().reset_index(name='number_of_entities')

print (df2)

   created_at  number_of_entities
0  2017-10-27                   4
1  2017-10-29                   4
```

Answer (score 2):

Given you data:

```
In [3]: df
Out[3]: 
            created_at                                           entities
0  2017-10-29 23:06:28  {'hashtags': [{'text': 'OPEC', 'indices': [0, ...
1  2017-10-29 22:28:20  {'hashtags': [{'text': 'Iraq', 'indices': [21,...
2  2017-10-29 20:01:37  {'hashtags': [{'text': 'oil', 'indices': [58, ...
3  2017-10-29 20:00:14  {'hashtags': [{'text': 'oil', 'indices': [38, ...
4  2017-10-27 08:44:30  {'hashtags': [{'text': 'Iran', 'indices': [19,...
5  2017-10-27 08:44:10  {'hashtags': [{'text': 'Oil', 'indices': [17, ...
6  2017-10-27 08:43:13  {'hashtags': [{'text': 'Oil', 'indices': [0, 4...
7  2017-10-27 08:43:00    {'hashtags': [{'text': 'Iran', 'indices': [19,.
```

You can use [groupby(..).count()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.count.html) as follows to get what you want:

```
In [4]: df[["created_at"]].groupby(pd.to_datetime(df["created_at"]).dt.date).count().rename(columns={"created_at":"number_of_entities"}).reset_index()
    ...: 
Out[4]: 
   created_at  number_of_entities
0  2017-10-27                   4
1  2017-10-29                   4
```

**Notice that:**

if the `created_at` column is already in datetime format, you can simply use the following:

```
df[["created_at"]].groupby(df.created_at.dt.date).count().rename(columns={"created_at":"number_of_entities"}).reset_index()
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`floor`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.floor.html) or [`date`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.date.html) for remove times and then [`value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) for counting, last [`rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html) and [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.reset_index.html) for 2 columns `DataFrame`:

```
df = (df['created_at'].dt.floor('d')
                     .value_counts()
                     .rename_axis('created_at')
                     .reset_index(name='number_of_entities'))
print (df)
  created_at  number_of_entities
0 2017-10-29                   4
1 2017-10-27                   4
```

Or:

```
df = (df['created_at'].dt.date
                     .value_counts()
                     .rename_axis('created_at')
                     .reset_index(name='number_of_entities'))
```

If want avoid default sorting in `value_counts` pass parameter `sort=False`:

```
df = (df['created_at'].dt.floor('d')
                     .value_counts(sort=False)
                     .rename_axis('created_at')
                     .reset_index(name='number_of_entities'))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can group by day using `df.groupby(df.created_at.dt.day)`.

As for the function calculating the counts, for that we would need a full row, your datastructure looks very weird.